# Is there a term for saying 'all countries outside the United States' without using the word 'foreign'? (used with international audience)

Tags: word-choice, expressions, expression-choice

I have to come up with a short description/label/identifier to describe two geographical groups:

1. United States
2. All countries except the United States

The description would be read by a global audience so the term ***foreign*** won't work. It must be short since it will be need to be displayed on reports that don't allow for long descriptions. Currently ***US*** & ***EX-US*** is being used but that doesn't feel right to me. There has to be a term or a way to label this, right?

Comment: I would interpret EX-US meaning a place that *used* to be the US!

Comment: I assume "benighted heathens" is out of the question?

Comment: @Oldcat: for which group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have a table or diagram that lists several specific locations, and then has a section for everywhere else, it's common in business settings to refer to the latter as *ROW*, which stands for *Rest of World*. But if there are just two choices, US and everywhere else, *US* and *Non-US* would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: Awesome, I really like this one.

Comment: Yes the simplest way is just to define your categories and make a term for them. **US** and **International** is often used in American business.